# Remote webdriver - Passing firefox profile with Rest Client Extension (add-on)

Tags: java, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

Currently I am able to send a firefox profile over a RemoteWebDriver, but I am not able to send the RestCLient extension over the profile. 
I require a certain REST client extension(firefox add-on) to be available for my test case execution.

If I run the test case locally using firefox driver it works....but how do I achieve the same thing using RemoteWebDriver?

```
 File profileDirectory = new File("c://mach//lib//prof");
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 24):

After creating a [`FirefoxProfile`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) instance, transfer the profile using the [`DesiredCapabilities`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) API (`FirefoxDriver.PROFILE` = ["firefox_profile"](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Firefox_specific)):

```java
File profileDirectory = new File("c://mach//lib//prof");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Note: You don't have to create a profile in advance, the `FirefoxProfile` API offers several convenient methods ("[Method Summary](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html)" section) to compose a profile. For instance, if you want to launch Firefox with an extension pre-installed, use:

```java
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
File extension = new File("extension.xpi");
firefoxProfile.addExtension(extension);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Documentation for working with the remote web driver:

- [RemoteWebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/)
- [`RemoteWebDriver` Java API documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html)
- [Grid2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) (original answer) and [Grid4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_4/) (update for 2021)

Comment: I got this exception in line "RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);"                                                                                                                                                                                                  org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision:

Comment: You need to start selenium server to use RemoteWebDriver