# php & Selenium - Firefox always opens welcome page (FF 49.0.2, SE 2.53.1)

Tags: php, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616808/remote-webdriver-passing-firefox-profile-with-rest-client-extension-add-on/17032649#17032649) and answer on Stackoverflow. And [this page](https://seleniumatfingertips.wordpress.com/tag/disable-first-run-page-in-firefox/). I've also read [this page](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/FirefoxProfile). I've also found [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1962) which doesn't resolved my problem either.

I'm using Selenium 2.53.1, FF 49.0.2 on Windows 10. Here is my code for the Facebook Webdriver, it's basically their example just extended by the profile settings:

```
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->setPreference('browser.startup.homepage_override.mston', 'ignore');
$profile->setPreference('startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional', 'about:blank');
$profile->setPreference('browser.startup.homepage', 'about:blank');
$profile->setPreference('xpinstall.signatures.required', false);

$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$capabilities->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities, 4444);

$driver->get('http://docs.seleniumhq.org/');
```

But I'm still getting this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an `e` missing at the end of `mston`. I would also set the `browser.usedOnWindows10` to true:

```
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->setPreference('browser.startup.page', 0);
$profile->setPreference('browser.startup.homepage', 'about:blank');
$profile->setPreference('browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone', 'ignore');
$profile->setPreference('browser.usedOnWindows10', true);
$profile->setPreference('xpinstall.signatures.required', false);
```

Comment: Thank you! Stupid typo... guess I didn't copy and pasted the string completely...  Now I'm running into the next issue... Getting Selenium to work on this System is no fun. :( Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: