# Selenium include firefox profile into DesiredCapabilities for Remote Driver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-grid

My goal is to use *a previously saved FireFox browser profile* in *Remore Webdriver* at Selenium Grid.

I've tried to add a profile object to `DesiredCapabilities`, yet failed, being a serialization error. The following code I've composed based on [this JAVA code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17032649/1230477):

```
desired_cap = {'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'browserName': 'firefox',
           'marionette': True, 'browserstack.debug' : True}
profile_path= os.environ['APPDATA']+os.sep+os.path.join('Mozilla','Firefox','Profiles', 'rust_mozprofile.aaaabbbb')
profile_object = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
desired_cap['FirefoxDriver.PROFILE'] = profile_object
```

> Error: ...  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json__init__.py", line 244, in
>   dumps
>       return _default_encoder.encode(obj)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
>       chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
>       return _iterencode(o, 0)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
>       raise **TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") TypeError:  is not JSON serializable**

Any suggestions? **Is it ever possible** to *pass Firefox profile to Remote Webdriver*?

Comment: Can you consider updating us your exact use-case? Are you trying to use an existing Firefox Profile? Or trying to create a new Firefox Profile? Thanks.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I try to use an existing FireFox profile saved in the folder `rust_mozprofile.aaaabbbb`.

Comment: Check my updated Answer as per your Question `goal is to use a previously saved FireFox browser profile`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I load the profile locally with:

```
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(
        firefox_profile=profile_object,
    )
```

And remote.

```
self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=SELENIUM,
        browser_profile=profile_object,
        desired_capabilities= desired_cap
    )
```